# How to use two input/output stream in one socket

Tags: java

I want to make a client server application using java socket programming.
In this application I want to make login and signup program.
In the login program i want to use DataOutputStream() for sending username and password to server and in signup i want to use ObjectOutputStream() to send username and password to server.
So it is possible to use two types of Outputstream using one socket.
It will work or not.

Comment: The best way to know if it's going to work is to try. Did you try? What was your effort so far? This site will only help you if you put your own efforts to the solution. Please check the policies.

Comment: You should only wrap a stream once, unless you like confusion. You only need ObjectXxxStream if you are going to send objects (in which case use that) otherwise use DataXxxStream to send data.

Comment: I try this. Yes it is possible to make two stream on same socket. But when I close a OutputStream() it also closes socket connection . So there any method to close a I/o stream without closing socket connection.